# How can sinbad regenerate his body?

Tags: magi

On magi chapter 322, Sinbad want to go to sacred place, where the rukh and god exist. He was using his *Djinn* metal vessel to conquer the guardian of sacred palace. We could  see Sinbad got hit several times by some of guardian angel, some of those hit made some of Sinbad's body part separated like image below

[image]

How can sinbad heal his wound ?